# How to zoom the window screen using css?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have used zoom: 90% its working but when we using high chart its not working properly. hovering property not showing correct position. Need solution for showing window zoomed in small screen like(Laptop screen)

Anyone give alternative solution for zoom
we tried scale but its not expect our terms

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+jQuery+zoom+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

I never try it on a full window,
but maybe something like `body{ transform: scale(1.5); }` can be use for scale an element in css.
[scale example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)